# System freezes when trying to install Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, system-installation, freeze, inspiron

My Dell Inspiron 7567 Gaming laptop freezes when trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 for the first time.

I downloaded the Ubuntu 18.04 .iso file from the official Ubuntu website, used Rufus to burn the ISO into my 16GB Cruiser Glide USB stick, while following all the steps in the Ubuntu Installation guide.

I booted off of the USB drive, went into language, selected my language, but after a few moments, the mouse will work but only that. Everything else freezes. I tried again in run Ubuntu only mode. It freezes after some period of time. The mouse moves, but everything else is frozen.

I tried re-burning the drive, but it failed.
I tried `acpi=off`, but it also failed.

I noticed some error messages while booting, the image will be very shaky / unclear, but I think it will provide just enough information. The image and video is attached.

**System specs**

OS Name: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
  Version: 10.0.17134 Build 17134
  Other OS: Description Not Available
  OS Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation
  System Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
  System Model: Inspiron 15 7000 Gaming
  System Type: x64-based PC
  System SKU: 0798
  Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz, 2801 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
  BIOS Version/Date: Dell Inc. 1.1.0, 2017-08-17
  SMBIOS Version: 3.0
  Embedded Controller Version: 255.255
  BIOS Mode: UEFI
  BaseBoard Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
  BaseBoard Model: Not Available
  BaseBoard Name: Base Board
  Platform Role: Mobile
  Secure Boot State: On
  PCR7 Configuration: Elevation Required to View
  Windows Directory: C:\Windows
  System Directory: C:\Windows\system32
  Boot Device: \Device\HarddiskVolume2
  Hardware Abstraction Layer Version = "10.0.17134.1"
  Installed Physical Memory (RAM): 16.0 GB
  Total Physical Memory: 15.9 GB
  Available Physical Memory: 12.0 GB
  Total Virtual Memory: 18.7 GB
  Available Virtual Memory: 13.4 GB
  Page File Space: 2.88 GB
  Page File: C:\pagefile.sys
  Kernel DMA Protection: Off
  Virtualisation-based security: Not enabled
  Device Encryption Support: Elevation Required to View
  Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
  Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions: Yes
  Hyper-V - Virtualisation Enabled in Firmware: Yes
  Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection: Yes
  Drive partitioned in Disk 1 (D: drive), TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100, 5400RPM HDD, for 160000MB, or 156.25GB, unallocated.

I took out my personal information that is not relevant to solving the issue.

Link to Google Drive for error messages: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1e13ZL06StVl6Yx6d9iY9Ou0qweC89Rud

Answer (score 1):

The rufus program uses two methods to format a drive: iso and dd. The iso option uses legacy bios and dd uses UEFI. Whatever option you used first to format your drive, try using the other option. If you are having trouble formatting your flash drive, rufus should reformat it for you. If that does not work, try to boot up from it again and when it displays a keyboard and a person at the bottom of the screen, hit the tab button. Then hit enter on "English" and press enter again on "Try Ubuntu without installing." When the desktop appears, click the "Install Ubuntu" icon on the desktop.

Comment: _"The iso option uses legacy bios and dd uses UEFI"_ No, that is completely wrong. The ISO and DD options have __nothing__ to do with BIOS or UEFI. Both of ISO and DD can support BIOS and/or UEFI according to the ISO being used, so please be mindful not to spread inaccuracies.

You will be prompted to choose between ISO and DD mode when the ISO you selected is an ISOHybrid (which again, has __nothing__ to do with BIOS or UEFI). When that is the case, Rufus can either use file-extraction (ISO) or sector-by-sector (DD) copy mode to create the USB. That's all the difference there is.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks for clearing things up. That is why when you use ISO mode, you can see the files on the drive. When it extracts the image sector-by-sector with DD, the partition becomes unreadable, but is still bootable.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it (depending of whether the file system being used by the people who created the ISOHybrid is readable by Windows, which is usually not the case). That's actually the reason why Rufus recommends to use ISO mode first, so that you can still see the data on the drive. But if that doesn't work, then you should give a try to DD mode.